# How to check that value stored in register is a valid address in the code segment

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I'm writing a small x86 Assembly program on a Windows machine. At one point I want to check if the value stored in the EDX register is a valid address pointing to the code segment of the same program. Can anyone please tell me how and if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your program, put a label like this...

```
 The_Code_Starts_Here:
```

At the end of your program, put a label like this...

```
 The_Code_Ends_Here:
```

In your section where you want to question the validity of that address, do something like this...

```
 Cmp    Edx, The_Code_Starts_Here   ; Is it in the code segment ?
 Jb     Bombs_Away                  ; No, bomb out

 Cmp    Edx, The_Code_Ends_Here     ; Is it in the code segment ?
 Jae    Bombs_Away                  ; No, bomb out

                                    ; Else, good stuff, go on
```

If I screwed up on the `Jb` and `Ja` nomenclature, then just switch them.

Comment: Your last `ja` should be a `jae` because the address *The_Code_Ends_Here* already is beyond the code section.

Comment: This doesn't prove that you have a valid code pointer, only that you have A pointer into the code segment. It could point into the middle of an instruction.